# Changes in Property that implements INotifyPropertyChanged not being reflected in UI

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, data-binding, viewmodel

I am trying to implement the MVVM Pattern but unfortunately is taking longer than expected.

I have a ListView populated by an ObservableCollection of ContactsVm, Adding or Removing Contacts works perfectly, the problem comes when trying to change only one Item from this collection by selecting it.

The Xaml where I am setting my bindings:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ContactsToDisplay}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedContact, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  SeparatorColor="Black" 
                  ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding FirstName}" 
                              Detail="{Binding Id}">
                        <TextCell.ContextActions>
                            <MenuItem 
                                Text="Delete" 
                                IsDestructive="true" 
                                Clicked="Delete_OnClicked"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                        </TextCell.ContextActions>
                    </TextCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Its cs:

```
public ContactBookApp()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
                cfg.CreateMap<Contact, ContactVm>();
                cfg.CreateMap<ContactVm, Contact>();
            });

            BindingContext = new ContactBookViewModel(new ContactService(), new PageService(), new Mapper(config));

        }

        private void AddButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (BindingContext as ContactBookViewModel)?.AddContact();
        }

        private void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            (BindingContext as ContactBookViewModel)?.SelectContact(e.SelectedItem  as ContactVm);
        }


        private void Delete_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (BindingContext as ContactBookViewModel)?.DeleteContact((sender as MenuItem)?.CommandParameter as ContactVm);
        }
    }
```

My ViewModel, here the "problematic" part is the SelectContact method, I am posting the rest in case it helps:

```
public class ContactBookViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private readonly IContactService _contactService;
        private readonly IPageService _pageService;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private ContactVm _selectedContact;
        public ObservableCollection<ContactVm> ContactsToDisplay { get; set; }
        public ContactVm SelectedContact
        {
            get => _selectedContact;
            set => SetValue(ref _selectedContact, value);
        }
        public ContactBookViewModel(IContactService contactService, IPageService pageService, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _contactService = contactService;
            _pageService = pageService;
            _mapper = mapper;
            LoadContacts();
        }
        private void LoadContacts()
        {
            List<Contact> contactsFromService = _contactService.GetContacts();
            List<ContactVm> contactsToDisplay = _mapper.Map<List<Contact>, List<ContactVm>>(contactsFromService);
            ContactsToDisplay = new ObservableCollection<ContactVm>(contactsToDisplay);

        }

        public void SelectContact(ContactVm contact)
        {
            if (contact == null)
                return;
            //None of this approaches works:
            //SelectedContact.FirstName = "Test";
            //contact.FirstName = "Test;
        }
    }
}
```

My ContactVm class:

```
public class ContactVm : BaseViewModel
    {
        private string _firstName;

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName
        {
            get => _firstName;
            set => SetValue(ref _firstName, value);
        }   
    }
```

The BaseViewModel:

```
public class BaseViewModel
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        protected void SetValue<T>(ref T backingField, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingField, value))
                return;
            backingField = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I am trying to update each selected contact setting its FirstName = "Test", the changed are updated but unfortunately they are not getting reflected in the UI, hope you can help me to find what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can I at least know why my question is downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your BaseViewModel does not implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: Yes. That is what I have mentioned in my answer as well. Hope you got that working fine. Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: @Victor You're welcome to accept my answer, if it solved your problem.

Comment: Not really, but whatever.

Comment: It is now? please check it

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you had used MVVM , you could handle the logic diretly in your ViewModel when you select item in listview (you don't need to define ItemSelected event any more) .

```
private ContactVm _selectedContact;

public ContactVm SelectedContact
{
   set
   {
      if (_selectedContact!= value)
      {
          _selectedContact= value;

          SelectedContact.FirstName="Test";

          NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedContact");
      }
   }
   get { return _selectedContact; }
}
```

And don't forget to implement the **INotifyPropertyChanged**  to your model and viewmodel.

Comment: If it still does not work , you would better share your sample so that I can test it on my side .

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator` attribute is not properly notifying the property changes. But I am not sure about that. Because your BaseViewModel does not implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

The below code works fine for me. This is how I use it in my entire project.

I have directly derived the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in my `BaseModel` and implemented the property changes.

```
public class BaseModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public class ContactVm : BaseModel
{
    private string _firstName;

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            this._firstName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have in my callback.

```
public void SelectContact(ContactVm contact)
{
    if (contact == null)
        return;
    contact.FirstName = "Test";
}
```

The only difference is I have implemented property changes for the ObservableCollection in ViewModel too.

```
public ObservableCollection<ContactVm> ContactsToDisplay 
{
    get { return _contactsToDisplay; }
    set
    {
        this._contactsToDisplay = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Note that I have not used your SelectedContact binding in my case. May be as you said that binding would be the issue.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I just tested it and unfortunately it didn't work, maybe is something wrong with the bindings?

Comment: It works just fine for me. All I could see is your BaseViewModel does not implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Other than that the only difference is that I have property changed notification for my view model as well. I have also not bind the SelectedContact. May be that binding is unwanted and hence it might actually revert the changes happening. My modified answer, just works fine for me.